# Hexagon Voxel(Minecraft Like) Geometry

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I'm trying to make a map of hexagons following the example https://threejs.org/manual/#en/voxel-geometry .

How to make hexagons instead of cubes?

When I did the first option in the manual, it turned out to make a hexagonal mesh and position it.

[image]

The second one turned out to make the hexagon itself, but the class does not work with it.

Code: https://github.com/drPapus/HEX/blob/master/src/client/client.ts
[image]

```
  interface VoxelWorld{
  cellSize:number
  cellSliceSize:number
  cell:any
}

class VoxelWorld {
  static faces: any;

  constructor(cellSize: any) {
    this.cellSize = cellSize;
    this.cellSliceSize = cellSize * cellSize;
    this.cell = new Uint8Array(cellSize * cellSize * cellSize);
  }
  computeVoxelOffset(x:number, y:number, z:number) {
    const {cellSize, cellSliceSize} = this;
    const voxelX = MathUtils.euclideanModulo(x, cellSize) | 0;
    const voxelY = MathUtils.euclideanModulo(y, cellSize) | 0;
    const voxelZ = MathUtils.euclideanModulo(z, cellSize) | 0;
    return voxelY * cellSliceSize + voxelZ * cellSize + voxelX;
  }
  getCellForVoxel(x:number, y:number, z:number) {
    const {cellSize} = this;
    const cellX = Math.floor(x / cellSize);
    const cellY = Math.floor(y / cellSize);
    const cellZ = Math.floor(z / cellSize);
    if (cellX !== 0 || cellY !== 0 || cellZ !== 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.cell;
  }
  setVoxel(x:number, y:number, z:number, v:number) {
    const cell = this.getCellForVoxel(x, y, z);
    if (!cell) {
      return;  // TODO: add a new cell?
    }
    const voxelOffset = this.computeVoxelOffset(x, y, z);
    cell[voxelOffset] = v;
  }
  getVoxel(x:number, y:number, z:number) {
    const cell = this.getCellForVoxel(x, y, z);
    if (!cell) {
      return 0;
    }
    const voxelOffset = this.computeVoxelOffset(x, y, z);
    return cell[voxelOffset];
  }
  generateGeometryDataForCell(cellX:any, cellY:any, cellZ:any) {
    const {cellSize} = this;
    const positions:any[] = [];
    const normals:any[] = [];
    const indices:any[] = [];
    const startX:number = cellX * cellSize;
    const startY:number = cellY * cellSize;
    const startZ:number = cellZ * cellSize;

    for (let y = 0; y < cellSize; ++y) {
      const voxelY = startY + y;
      for (let z = 0; z < cellSize; ++z) {
        const voxelZ = startZ + z;
        for (let x = 0; x < cellSize; ++x) {
          const voxelX = startX + x;
          const voxel = this.getVoxel(voxelX, voxelY, voxelZ);
          if (voxel) {
            for (const {dir, corners} of VoxelWorld.faces) {
              const neighbor = this.getVoxel(
                  voxelX + dir[0],
                  voxelY + dir[1],
                  voxelZ + dir[2]
                  );
              if (!neighbor) {
                const ndx = positions.length / 3;
                for (const pos of corners) {
                  positions.push(pos[0] + x, pos[1] + y, pos[2] + z);
                  normals.push(...dir);
                }
                indices.push(
                  ndx, ndx + 1, ndx + 2,
                  ndx + 2, ndx + 1, ndx + 3,
                );
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return {
      positions,
      normals,
      indices,
    };
  }
}

let t = 0.5 * Math.sqrt(3);

VoxelWorld.faces = [

  { // bottom
    dir: [],
    corners: [
    [ 0.5, -1,  t],  
    [-0.5, -1,  t], 
    [ 0.5, -1, -t],  
    [-0.5, -1, -t],
    ],
  },
{
  dir: [],
    corners: [
    [0.5, -1,  0], 
    [0.5, -1, -t], 
    [0.5, -1,  t],  
    [1.0, -1,  0],   
    ],
  },
  {
    dir: [],
      corners: [
      [-0.5, -1, 0], 
      [-0.5, -1, t], 
      [-0.5, -1,-t],  
      [-1.0, -1, 0],   
      ],
    },

    { // top
      dir: [0, -1,  0,],
      corners: [
      [-0.5, 1,  t],  
      [ 0.5, 1,  t], 
      [-0.5, 1, -t],  
      [ 0.5, 1, -t],
      ],
    },
  {
    dir: [],
      corners: [
      [-0.5, 1,  0], 
      [-0.5, 1, -t], 
      [-0.5, 1,  t],  
      [-1.0, 1,  0],   
      ],
    },
    {
      dir: [],
        corners: [
        [0.5, 1, 0], 
        [0.5, 1, t], 
        [0.5, 1,-t],  
        [1.0, 1, 0],   
        ],
      },

  { // A
    dir: [ -1,  0,  0, ],
    corners: [
    [-0.5,  1,  t],  // 6   0
    [-1.0,  1,  0],  // 7   1 
    [-0.5, -1,  t],  // 8   0B
    [-1.0, -1,  0],  // 9   1B
    ],
  },

  { // B
    dir: [  1,  0,  0, ],
    corners: [
    [-1.0,  1,  0],  // 10  1
    [-0.5,  1, -t],  // 11  2
    [-1.0, -1,  0],  // 12  1B
    [-0.5, -1, -t],  // 13  2B
    ],
  },
  { // C
    dir: [  0,  0, -1, ],
    corners: [
    [-0.5,  1, -t],  // 14  2
    [ 0.5,  1, -t],  // 15  3
    [-0.5, -1, -t],  // 16  2B
    [ 0.5, -1, -t],  // 17  3B
    ],
  },
  { //  D
    dir: [  0,  0,  1, ],
    corners: [
    [0.5,  1, -t],  // 18  3
    [1.0,  1,  0],  // 19  4
    [0.5, -1, -t],  // 20  3B        
    [1.0, -1,  0],  // 21  4B
    ],
  },
  { // E
    dir:[],
    corners: [
     [1.0, 1,  0],  // 22  4
     [0.5, 1,  t],  // 23  5
     [1.0, -1, 0],  // 24  4B
     [0.5, -1, t],  // 25  5B
    ]
  },
  { //F
    dir: [],
    corners: [
    [ 0.5,  1,  t],  // 26  5
    [-0.5,  1,  t],  // 27  0
    [ 0.5, -1,  t],  // 28  5B
    [-0.5, -1,  t],  // 29  0B
    ],
  },
];
(async function(){
    let pmrem = new PMREMGenerator(renderer);
    let envmapTexture = await new RGBELoader().setDataType(FloatType).loadAsync("assets/envmap.hdr");
    envmap = pmrem.fromEquirectangular(envmapTexture).texture
    const simplex = new SimplexNoise 

const world = new VoxelWorld(cellSize);

  for (let y = 0; y < cellSize; ++y) {
    for (let z = 0; z < cellSize; ++z) {
      for (let x = 0; x < cellSize; ++x) {
        const height = (Math.sin(x / cellSize * Math.PI * 2) + Math.sin(z / cellSize * Math.PI * 3)) * (cellSize / 6) + (cellSize / 2);
        if (y < height) {
          world.setVoxel(x, y, z, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const {positions, normals, indices} = world.generateGeometryDataForCell(0, 0, 0);
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

  const material = new MeshStandardMaterial({
                 envMap: envmap,
                 flatShading: true
             })
  const positionNumComponents = 3;
  const normalNumComponents = 3;
  geometry.setAttribute(
      'position',
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(positions), positionNumComponents));
  geometry.setAttribute(
      'normal',
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(normals), normalNumComponents));
  geometry.setIndex(indices);
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's solved:
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMDI6.jpg)

```
 const cellSize = 1;
 const worldSize = 128;
// CONFIG =============================================================================================
let envmap;
let hexagonGeometries = new BoxGeometry(0,0,0);
interface VoxelWorld {
    cellSize:number
    worldSize:number
    cellSliceSize:number
    cell:any
    cellSizeWidth:number
    cellSizeHeight:number
    cellSizeDepth:number
}



//////////////////////////////
interface VoxelWorld{
  cellSize:number
  cellSliceSize:number
  cell:any
}


class VoxelWorld {
  static faces: any = newPrismFaces;

  constructor(cellSize: any, worldSize: any) {
    this.worldSize = worldSize;
    this.cellSize = cellSize;
    this.cellSliceSize = cellSize * cellSize;

    this.cellSizeWidth = cellSize * Math.sqrt(3);
    this.cellSizeHeight = cellSize * 2;
    this.cellSizeDepth = cellSize;

    this.cell = new Uint8Array(worldSize * worldSize * worldSize);
}
 //вычислить смещение вокселя
  computeVoxelOffset(x:number, y:number, z:number) {
    const {cellSize, cellSliceSize} = this;
    const voxelX = MathUtils.euclideanModulo(x, worldSize) | 0;
    const voxelY = MathUtils.euclideanModulo(y, worldSize) | 0;
    const voxelZ = MathUtils.euclideanModulo(z, worldSize) | 0;
    let offset = voxelY * worldSize * worldSize
    + voxelZ * worldSize
    + voxelX;
return offset
  }
//получить ячейку для вокселя
  getCellForVoxel(x:number, y:number, z:number) {
    const {cellSize} = this;
    const cellX = Math.floor(x / worldSize);
    const cellY = Math.floor(y / worldSize);
    const cellZ = Math.floor(z / worldSize);
    if (cellX !== 0 || cellY !== 0 || cellZ !== 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.cell;
  }

  //установить воксель

  setVoxel(x:number, y:number, z:number, v:number) {
    const cell = this.getCellForVoxel(x, y, z);
    if (!cell) {
      return;  // TODO: add a new cell?
    }
    const voxelOffset = this.computeVoxelOffset(x, y, z);
    cell[voxelOffset] = v;
  }
//получить воксель
  getVoxel(x:number, y:number, z:number) {
    const cell = this.getCellForVoxel(x, y, z);
    if (!cell) {
      return 0;
    }
    const voxelOffset = this.computeVoxelOffset(x, y, z);
    return cell[voxelOffset];
  }

  //генерировать данные геометрии для ячейки

  generateGeometryDataForCell(cellX:any, cellY:any, cellZ:any) {
    const {cellSizeWidth, cellSizeHeight, cellSizeDepth, worldSize} = this;
    const positions:any[] = [];
    const normals:number[] = [];
    const indices:number[] = [];
    const startX:number = cellX * worldSize;
    const startY:number = cellY * worldSize;
    const startZ:number = cellZ * worldSize;

    for (let y = 0; y < worldSize; ++y) {
        const voxelY = startY + y;
        for (let z = 0; z < worldSize; ++z) {
            const voxelZ = startZ + z;
            for (let x = 0; x < worldSize; ++x) {
                const voxelX = startX + x;
                const voxel = this.getVoxel(voxelX, voxelY, voxelZ);
                if (!voxel) {continue;}

                // Тут вокселю нужно знать где стороны/фэйсы
                for (const {side, dir, corners} of VoxelWorld.faces) {
                    let dirX = dir[0];
                    let dirY = dir[1];
                    let dirZ = dir[2];

                    if ('bcfe'.includes(side)) {dirX += z % 2}

                    const neighbor = this.getVoxel(
                        voxelX + dirX,
                        voxelY + dirY,
                        voxelZ + dirZ,
                    );

                    // Есть сосед - не рисуем грань
                    if (neighbor) {continue;}

                    // у этого вокселя нет соседей в этом направлении, поэтому рисуем грань.
                    const ndx = positions.length / 3;
                    for (const pos of corners) {
                        positions.push(
                            pos[0] + x * cellSizeWidth + (z % 2 * (cellSizeWidth / 2)),
                            pos[1] + y * cellSizeDepth,
                            pos[2] + z * cellSizeHeight - (z * .5)
                        );
                        normals.push(...dir);
                    }
                    indices.push(
                        ndx, ndx + 1, ndx + 2,
                        ndx + 2, ndx + 1, ndx + 3,
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        positions,
        normals,
        indices,
    };
}
}


(async function(){

    let pmrem = new PMREMGenerator(renderer);
    let envmapTexture = await new RGBELoader().setDataType(FloatType).loadAsync("assets/envmap.hdr");
    envmap = pmrem.fromEquirectangular(envmapTexture).texture

    const simplex = new SimplexNoise 

/////
const world = new VoxelWorld(cellSize, worldSize);

  for (let y = 0; y < worldSize; ++y) {
    for (let z = 0; z < worldSize; ++z) {
      for (let x = 0; x < worldSize; ++x) {
        const height =
        (Math.sin(x / worldSize * Math.PI * 2) + Math.sin(z / worldSize * Math.PI * 3))
        * (worldSize / 6)
        + (worldSize / 2);
        if (y < height) {
          world.setVoxel(x, y, z, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const {positions, normals, indices} = world.generateGeometryDataForCell(0, 0, 0);
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

  const material = new MeshStandardMaterial({
                 envMap: envmap,
                 flatShading: true
             })

  const positionNumComponents = 3;
  const normalNumComponents = 3;
  geometry.setAttribute(
      'position',
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(positions), positionNumComponents));
  geometry.setAttribute(
      'normal',
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(normals), normalNumComponents));
  geometry.setIndex(indices);
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);



let geo = new CylinderGeometry(1,1, 1, 6, 1, false);
let hex = new Mesh( geo, material)
//scene.add(hex);

const positionAttribute = hex.geometry.getAttribute( 'position' ); 
const vertex:any = new THREE.Vector3();
let points:any[] = []

for ( let vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < positionAttribute.count; vertexIndex ++ ) {
vertex.fromBufferAttribute( positionAttribute, vertexIndex );

 points.push( new THREE.Vector3(vertex.x, vertex.y ,vertex.z))
}



//LINE
const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( geometry );
const line = new THREE.LineSegments( edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ) );
scene.add( line );


    renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{
        //hexagonMesh.rotation.x += 0.01
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    })
})();

import {cellSize} from "./_config";

// Size
const s = cellSize;
// 1/2 Size
const s12 = cellSize / 2;
// Width
const w = s * Math.sqrt(3);
// 1/2 width
const w12 = w / 2;
// Height
const h = s * 2;


/*
      3 -- 4
     /      \                 x - red, y - green, z - blue
    2        5                 +x
     \      /                   |
      1 -- 0               -z ---- +z
                                |
         D                     -x
       3 -- 4
    C /      \ E
     2        5
    B \      / F
       1 -- 0
         A
                   ______
                  /      \
           ______/  1.1   \
          /      \        /
         /  1.0   \______/
         \        /      \
          \______/  0.1   \
          /      \        /
         /  0.0   \______/
         \        /
          \______/
          ^
         0.0.0

*/

const newPrismFaces = [
    // BOTTOM ====================================================
    { // start
        side: 'bs',
        dir:[0, -1, 0],
        corners: [
            [w, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0],
            [w12, 0, -s12],
            [0, 0, 0],
        ]
    },
    { // center
        side: 'bc',
        dir: [0, -1,  0],
        corners: [
            [w, 0, s],
            [0, 0, s],
            [w, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0],
        ],
    },
    { // end
        side: 'be',
        dir:[0, -1, 0],
        corners: [
            [0, 0, s],
            [w, 0, s],
            [w12, 0, s + s12],
            [w, 0, s],
        ]
    },
    // TOP ========================================================
    { // start
        side: 'ts',
        dir:[0, 1, 0],
        corners: [
            [0, s, 0],
            [w, s, 0],
            [w12, s, -s12],
            [w, s, 0],
        ]
    },
    { // center
        side: 'tc',
        dir: [0, 1,  0],
        corners: [
            [0, s, s],
            [w, s, s],
            [0, s, 0],
            [w, s, 0],
        ],
    },
    { // end
        side: 'te',
        dir:[0, 1, 0],
        corners: [
            [w, s, s],
            [0, s, s],
            [w12, s, s + s12],
            [0, s, s],
        ]
    },
    // LATERAL SIDES ===============================================
    { // A
        side: 'a',
        dir: [-1, 0, 0],
        corners: [
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, s],
            [0, s, 0],
            [0, s, s],
        ],
    },
    { // B
        side: 'b',
        dir: [-1, 0, -1],
        corners: [
            [w12, 0, -s12],
            [0, 0, 0],
            [w12, s, -s12],
            [0, s, 0],
        ],
    },
    { // C
        side: 'c',
        dir: [0, 0, -1],
        corners: [
            [w, 0, 0],
            [w12, 0, -s12],
            [w, s, 0],
            [w12, s, -s12],
        ],
    },
    { // D
        side: 'd',
        dir: [ 1, 0, 0],
        corners: [
            [w, 0, s],
            [w, 0, 0],
            [w, s, s],
            [w, s, 0],
        ],
    },
    { // E
        side: 'e',
        dir: [ 0, 0, 1],
        corners: [
            [w12, 0, s + s12],
            [w, 0, s],
            [w12, s, s + s12],
            [w, s, s],
        ],
    },
    { // F
        side: 'f',
        dir: [-1, 0, 1],
        corners: [
            [0, 0, s],
            [w12, 0, s + s12],
            [0, s, s],
            [w12, s, s + s12],
        ],
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, this is greatly appreciated. What would help in the future is to get some information on what they key difference is, or where the poster went wrong.